# Redis Query regarding slave to master promotion

Tags: redis

I have following redis configuration:

Machine 1 - 1 redis master ; 1 redis sentinel
Machine 2 - 1 redis slave ; 1 redis sentinel.

When I shutdown the redis master of machine 1 then redis slave of machine 2 gets promoted to master role.

However, now if i restarted redis server on machine 1 and shutdown redis server on machine 2 then redis on machine 1 does not get promoted to master . Is this the intended behaviour and if so then why.?